# Is there a common base class for records?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

In the .NET type system all reference types derive from `System.Object`, all value types from `System.ValueType` I think. Is there also a common base class all `record` types are derived from? If not, why not?

Comment: `ValueType` is derived from `object` too.

Comment: They are normal classes with no special base class and implementing `IEquatable<T>` with some specially named methods. Strangely they don't even have a descriptor `Attribute` of any type to distinguish them or a special interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there also a common base class all record types are derived from?

No, at least not anything specific to records.  Records are just reference types.  They can derive directly from `System.Object` or from other record types.

> If not, why not?

They don't require special handling by the runtime like value types do.  Everything that's special about them is in the code that the compiler generates for them.

---

### "Root" Records

A record can derive directly from `System.Object`, either implicitly or explicitly, just as any `class` can.  That first level of record type bootstraps the internals of a record, establishing the root of a record type hierarchy.

1. **Copy constructor** -- A protected constructor that accepts a reference to the same type and copies its properties.  Derived records will call this from their copy constructors.
2. **Clone method** -- It's essentially what `ICloneable<T>.Clone()` *would* have been had it ever been a part of the Base Class Library, but this one has an unaddressable name: `<Clone>$`.  When you use the `with` keyword, it calls `<Clone>$`, which creates a new instance using the copy constructor, and then the compiler allows any init-only properties to be set within the initializer expression.
3. **Equality members** -- This is the big one, since records are about *value semantics*.  The `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods from `System.Object` are overridden, and `IEquatable<T>.Equals()` is implemented.  There's also a protected property named `EqualityContract` which is used in the equality comparison to ensure that records of different types are not considered equal by comparing only the common parts.  The `==` and `!=` operators are overloaded, as well.
4. **`ToString` method** -- Overloaded to display the members of the record.  It uses a protected `PrintMembers` method, which is called up the class hierarchy to build the string with all the properties' values.
5. **`Deconstruct` method** -- Enables the record to be deconstructed into individual variables.

---

### Derived records

When you specify a base type (other than `System.Object`) for a record type, it must be another record type because it requires the mechanisms established by the root of the record type hierarchy.  The derived record type defines the same members, but members that were marked `virtual` are now marked `override`.

1. **Copy constructor** -- This will call the base record's copy constructor.
2. **Clone method** -- `<Clone>$` is overridden to return the more derived type using its copy constructor.

> ***Fun fact:*** This *does not* use the new covariant returns feature to *declare* a more derived return type on the overridden method, even though it returns a more derived type.  That's because 1) it doesn't need to, and 2) it would've made records unusable except in .NET 5.0 since support for the feature was added in the .NET 5.0 runtime.

3. **Equality members** -- The same methods are overridden and operators defined, but with any new properties considered for equality.
4. **`ToString` method** -- `ToString` and `PrintMembers` are overridden.  `ToString` produces the actual class name and curly braces in the string.  The base implementation is not called.  `PrintMembers` separately builds the property names and values.
5. **`Deconstruct` method** -- There's no overriding here because the base class's method isn't marked `virtual`.  If new properties are introduced, the signature is different from that of the base class so there's nothing to override.  If no new properties are introduced, the method is marked `new` to shadow the one in the base class.

---

That is why a special base type for records isn't necessary.

---

**Special notes:**

When a record is marked `sealed`, members that normally would be `protected virtual` (but not `protected override`) become `private`.  How extensive that is depends on whether it derives from `System.Object` or another record type.

None of the above takes into account customization by way of providing your own implementation of any of the methods that are normally implemented by the compiler.

Comment: Excellent answer. Is there a way to "trick" the compiler into treating a normal class like a record? Eg, by implementing the members described above.

Comment: No, at least not at this time. The compiler team may eventually want to look into a convention-based approach to hooking into this functionality, but they would have to weigh the cost of implementation against the benefits, as they do with all new features. Records are already pretty complex.