# Why is the C# 9.0 "with expression" exclusive to records?

Tags: c#, language-specifications, c#-9.0

Reading through the spec for C# 9.0 I came across `record` and the new [`with` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression). Immediately I thought this was great for all my immutable structs, such as vectors and matrices! However it turns out that the `with` expression *only works on records*. **How come?** Does the `with` expression require something that only a `record` is guaranteed to have (equality members perhaps)?

I can understand the argument that structs don't need it since they are value types and simply assigning the value to a new variable is enough to create a copy, but the syntax would be nice and surely it would be useful to create copies like that even for normal classes, not just records?

Comment: `with` expressions use the protected `<Clone>$` method. Non-record types can't declare such a method. I wrote a bit about the boilerplate code in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65422383/5394572).

Comment: "*How come?*" questions are not very satisfying for anyone. The only valid answer is "*because it does*" Yes sure there is usually a discussion trail to these language features, but it will be hit and miss if they can address a specific question like this. Secondly, asking why they didn't implement further features is futile, maybe they didn't think of it, maybe it would require too many changes, maybe its just a bad idea and it was never discussed. In the end this question because too broad, and opinion based

Comment: *"Does the with expression require something that only a record is guaranteed to have?"* is a pretty concrete question, though. The title isn't always the actual question. I'm not sure if the answer I linked actually answers the question so I didn't flag it; if it does, it does so indirectly.

Comment: @madreflection agreed, but there is more to unpack here, and several musings and sub questions in play. The perfect answer by Eric Lippert https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673015/1612975

Comment: FYI: C# 10 now allows with expressions on all structs.