# Is there a way to make the "with expression" work with classes?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

As far as I know, the `with` expression can only be used with records and structs. The `with` expression creates a new instance of an object with the specified new values and copying all others (with special semantics for types with copy constructors).

```
record Record(int A, int B);
var someRecord = new Record(1, 2); // Record(1, 2)
var copy = someRecord with { B = 99 }; // Record(1, 99)
```

However, this construct does not work with classes. If you try, you'll get a compiler error.

> CS8858 The receiver type '[Type]' is not a valid record type and is not a struct type.

There are other various extensions to support newer syntax like extension add for collections or extension deconstruct but I don't believe there's an equivalent for `with` expressions. Options are to create and use an explicit copy constructor and set the new values afterwards, or copying fields over manually which can be a lot for larger classes.

```
// with copy constructor
var copy2 = new SomeClass(someInstance) { SomeProperty = "someValue" };
// manually copying
var copy3 = new SomeClass { Property = someInstance.Property, SomeProperty = "someValue" };
```

Is there an equivalent extension syntax for the `with` expression or other construct to make this work for classes or similar?

I'm working with a lot of data objects and have resorted to using an mapper to clone the object, then update the fields. I would prefer to reduce the needed code for this. And adding copy constructors everywhere isn't always feasible.

```
var copy4 = Mapper.Map<SomeClass>(someInstance);
copy4.SomeProperty = "someValue";
```

Comment: In short, no. Record types have user-inaccessible supporting members, including a clone method and a "copy constructor" used by `with`. I described that supporting functionality and more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65422383).